# How much is *enough* reputation?

Tags: discussion, jobs

**How much rep is *enough rep* in relation to Stack Overflow and [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/about)? 10K? 50K?**

Comment: We need a close-as-pointless-question reason

Comment: Self-deprivation trumps pointlessness, at least when well written; Stack Overflow has a culture/specification that somewhat promotes a tad to zealous question/answer/whatnot ethic....but of course, I would never want to go back to the old forum days....I just realized that I am commenting on form, and good syntactic mastery, rather than your post, so I guess my boat is sinking faster than yours at the moment ;-)

Comment: ... but are you programming on your sinking boat?  That's the real question.

Comment: See revision 2 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/29711/list

Comment: so...if I have under say, 1000 rep, is careers a waste of my time?

Comment: Is that site about answering questions or to get a kick out of getting more and more votes?

Comment: How much is *enough* Money for you?

Comment: @MortenBergfall Self-deprivation or self-_deprecation_? They're rather different!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Somewhere around <strike>12.5K</strike> 22.5K.

Enough to get you access to <strike>[the moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools)</strike> [trusted user status](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) and a buffer to allow for down-votes, bounties and rep recalculations.

But then again if you've got that much it will never be "enough" as you'll want to keep your place on page 7 or even get up to page 6 (and then page 5...)

**EDIT 8th Jan 2010**

As an interesting aside 12.5k rep now gets you onto page 9. To get onto page 7 you'll need 13.5K. So in two months you'd need to get approximately 1K rep to keep your place at this level. 500 points a month shouldn't be too hard to keep up for a moderately active user.

Comment: So, "never enough."  I concur. :)

Comment: for the time being I am comfortable enough fighting into the pit around page 35

Comment: @JohnIdol - page 7 is (roughly) where 12.5k rep will get you (as of Nov 2009).

Comment: So you will never get enough, unless you get it fast

Answer (score 46):

You have enough rep when Jon Skeet is in second place.

Comment: Your answer can be refactored to make it more clear: "You will never have enough rep."

Comment: @Jon B. Using any decent compiler this answer would be optimized out completely.

Comment: Actually, I am pretty sure that the compiler would do neither of these.  It would just stop compiling and laugh at you.

Answer (score 20):

Think from the point of view of a person looking to hire, *who is the kind of person you want to work for*. If that person were me, I'd be looking for someone who knows how to communicate well, and who is largely correct.

I can't actually tell that from just the rep score. I can get *some* idea if I know the average number of votes that person gets per answer. I can improve that by knowing what tags that person is active in (as upvotes are easier to come by in popular tags). But the only way I'll really know is by reading the person's answers.

*Maybe* I'd use rep just as a very crude first pass filter, discarding anyone with less than 1K - why would they want to use SO Careers if they're not really invested in SO? - but anything above that and I'd be interested in the details, not a number.

Now leaving careers aside, I think anything above about 93K is respectable.

Comment: Woo hoo...just another 100 days and I achieve respectability!  ;-)

Comment: @tvanfosson: Well, the bar is always rising of course... at about the rate that Marc Gravell gains rep ;)

Comment: ...and my parents were going to be so proud. :-(

Comment: Could we hear Jon Skeet's seal of approval level: how much rep per answer is OK?  For instance, is 18.3 enough?

Comment: @Pavel: Votes per answer is more interesting than rep per answer, due to the rep cap. Unfortunately that's hard to work out for other users (beyond the top N) - but the "any tag" stats page should help you work it out for yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=&sort=stats&pagesize=50

Comment: completely agree its all about the details... but with a twist, employers will probably only look at your user page, and their initial pass will probably only look at the top 10/20 questions and answers.

Comment: "I think anything above about 93K is respectable." - lol ;-p

Comment: The ironic thing is, if you have enough rep to get hired by a company that uses it as the only way to screen candidates on SOC, you probably don't want to work for that company.

Comment: Actually, I've come to agree with you... 93K sounds about right ;-p (cue Jon increasing the number...)

Answer (score 17):

The perfect amount of rep is 42.

Comment: Hundred or thousand? ;)

Comment: What was the question again?

Comment: Thats Why i named my company 42 consulting :D

Answer (score 9):

- [Reputation != A for effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471940/why-does-every-man-and-his-dog-want-to-code-a-blogging-engine/471944#471944) (alternative link Spolskys [500 pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/871420#871420))

A much better measure is quality. Employers will probable look at your [home page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron).

- Are there any answers there that are of poor quality?
- Are there any outrageously bad questions there?
- What tags are you active on?
- Is your bio riddled with horrid phrasing and spelling? Too many jokes perhaps?
- Is there enough information there for them to make some sort of decision?

I would argue that even 500-1000 reputation can be enough as long as your home page is all quality.

Comment: Discussiony? Discussionish? Discoteque?

Answer (score 4):

It's not about the size of your boat, but the motion of the ocean, and if you're programming on said boat.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the 7000s on SO, and the 3000s here, and feel comfortable with my rep. Would I like more? Sure, we all would!

So technically, there's never such a thing as "enough," but the truth is that once you're comfortably able to edit and vote-to-close, you're probably there. That said, rep is only one facet of the site -- it's not like people who *really* want to contribute stop just because they've rep-capped, or they're not likely to gain rep from an answer. At least, that hasn't stopped me. (Although I think I've only rep-capped 3 times ... and two of those were here on Meta.)

Answer (score 3):

It's never enough!

```
# Hold on! It's never enough
# It's never enough until your heart stops beating
# The deeper you get, the sweeter the pain
# Don't give up the game until your heart stops beating.
```

*"Skeetshocked"*, by New Waffels

Answer (score 2):

Well, the threshold to get free stickers was around 20k.

But there are those who feel too high a reputation will hurt you in terms of job hunting.

The 10k moderation tools aren't something worth getting reputation points *just* to get.

In order to have a buffer for bounty, and do most of the editing you might ever want, I'd say right around 7-8k is good.

Comment: I got stickers and I only had 4k rep on meta

Comment: Yes, Meta, SU, and SF had much lower thresholds for first and second page users than SO.

Comment: I got an email offering SO stickers, but I never bothered to give them my address.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you want just enough rep to appear on page 3 or 4. More than that employers maybe think you spend too much time on SO, less than that maybe they don't think you shine so much. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

10k gives you all the functionality you need - so anything above that is just useless.

Comment: Were you referring to Stackoverflow reputation or Visual Studio pricing?

Comment: 10k hit points on the stack overflow gives you everything but moderator powers as far as I know