# What is the benefit to make big reputation on SO? Can i get good job from it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, jobs

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How much is *enough* reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29672/how-much-is-enough-reputation) 
>   [Is Stack Overflow reputation marketable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30578/is-stack-overflow-reputation-marketable)

What is the benefit to get big reputation on SO? Can i get good job from it?

Comment: With determination and some luck, you can.

Comment: I do it for the warm fuzzy feeling.

Answer (score 3):

e-Glory, of course.

Can you get a job with e-glory? Perhaps. Perhaps not. But at the end of the day, even if you're unemployed, and down to your last dollar, and your best girl is through with you...

By golly you've still got your stackoverflow rep :D

Comment: what is e-Glory? What is golly?

Comment: e-glory is online reputation.... golly is just an expression. So what does 'Jitendra" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Most people using SO as a hiring point would most likely be looking at the quality of the answers you give and not just what big number is next to your name.